# How can I collect code coverage when testing a .NET webservice using mstest?

Tags: .net, web-services, code-coverage, mstest

I'd like to use `MSTest` to collect code coverage not only for classic unit tests but also for calls made against a webservice. I am using `Visual Studio 2013` with the latest updates.

I've got the source code and also the binaries (including `PDB` files if needed), but unfortunately I my attempts so far didn't work.

I tried to configure the `.runsettings` file in my test project to point to the directory where the binaries for the webservice are available and also set the `SymbolSearchPath` to that directory:

```
...
<CodeCoverage>
    <ModulePaths>
        <Exclude>
            <ModulePath>.*CPPUnitTestFramework.*</ModulePath>
        </Exclude>
        <Include>
            <ModulePath>\\AValidPathTo\My.dll</ModulePath>
        </Include>
    </ModulePaths>
</CodeCoverage>

<SymbolSearchPaths>
    <Path>\\AValidPathTo\My\Binaries</Path>
</SymbolSearchPaths>
...
```

Code coverage seems to ignore these settings - I made sure that the correct `.runsettings` file is selected via `Test` => `Test Settings`.

My second attempt was to follow the steps described in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2005/06/08/426979.aspx) - excerpt below:

1. Copy the desired product binaries, product PDBs, and test binaries files locally.
2. Instrument the product binaries: a.Open up a Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt (Start | All Programs | Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 | Visual Studio tools | Visual Studio Command Prompt). 
   b.Change to the directory where your binaries are located 
   c.Execute “vsinstr –coverage ” for all your binaries.  e.g. If your binary name is ‘coolproduct.dll’, then type “vsinstr –coverage coolproduct.dll”.
3. Start the Code Coverage monitoring process a.Return to the previous command prompt 
   b.Type “vsperfcmd –start:coverage –output:outputFilename.coverage”.
4. Execute your tests a.For automated tests, navigate to the directory where your test binaries are located and execute “mstest /testcontainer:TestDll.dll”. 
   b.Run manual tests, if you have them
5. End the Code Coverage monitoring process a.In the command prompt opened earlier, type “vsperfcmd –shutdown”.  This shuts down the coverage monitor and saves the coverage data to disk.

Unfortunately this also didn't work - after resigning the signed DLL (this was a necessary additional step) I ended up with a `.coverage` file without any data in it (and no error either).

What would be the steps for collecting code coverage for webservice calls using `MSTest`?

Comment: Potentially silly question but: MSTest runs unit tests, you've written unit tests to test your web service?

Comment: @PeterRitchie - Yes. The reason is that we aren't happy with the time it takes to create tests using other tools (such as soapUI, WcfStorm, ...). Using `mstest` we hope to benefit from the tight integration with Visual Studio. We also plan to execute such tests using the `MS Test Manager` which, according to the documentation, shouldn't be a problem. If, however, we are on the completely wrong track, other suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: This doesn't help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx ?  Perhaps you need to upgrage Visual Studio. Are you using 2005 or is that just from the blog post? VS 2005 is nearly 10 years old!

Comment: @Mick - Sorry that I didn't mention the version, I'm using VS2013 with the latest update. The link you provided doesn't help as it is meant for unit tests (we already use it to determine the code coverage). I am looking for a solution when testing web service methods.

Comment: I don't understand why unit tests can't be used on web service methods.  You can instantiate a web service class and call the method in a unit test.  Sure this doesn't test serialization, but you can create separate tests for that anyway.

Comment: @Mick: That's not the point. We use mstest for unit tests in the conventional way, including code coverage. The question here is not whether it is possible to use mstest for web service calls. The question is about code coverage when doing that ("What would be the steps for collecting code coverage for webservice calls using MSTest?").

Comment: Why does the web service method need to be invoked as an actual web service call from a web service client when all you're interested in is the code coverage?  You could just instantiate the web service as a normal class within the unit test, call the method like a normal method on a normal class from a unit test.  Presto, you have your coverage. The only catch would be if your web method is dependent on constructs like the WCF RequestContext or the classic WS HttpContext.  In that case you would need to mock those in the unit test

Comment: @Mick: By calling web service methods we want to achieve automated integration/system tests. As said before, we have conventional unit tests for the server side code. We have the unit tests on the lower level, integration tests (calling web service methods in our case) on a higher level and automated UI tests on the highest level.

Comment: Well if you really want code coverage whilst the application is effectively running you'll need a different tool... something like http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/application-performance-profiling/features/code-coverage-analysis/.  So the answer with the restrictions you've placed on it is no.  But I think what you're trying to do isn't necessary, you should be able to mock the web service calls in proc, without actually using a web service client making calls over the wire to achieve your goal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62328/discussion-between-gorgsenegger-and-mick).